# Protractor: Locating table rows with matching cell values

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Is it possible to to locate a table row inside an ng-repeat using exact values that should be present in the table cells?

I know I can retrieve particular columns using this syntax:

```
element(by.repeater('customer in vm.customers').row(0).column('customer.name')
```

In my case, I wont know what the index is yet.

So say I have a typical table declaration like so:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers">
        <td>
            {{customer.firstName}}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{customer.lastName}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I get the following output

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Bob
        </td>
        <td>
            Smith
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            James
        </td>
        <td>
            Tulley
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a locator I could use to say get me the row that contains Bob Smith?
I know this is not pretty but something like:

```
element(by.repeater('customer in vm.customers').column('customer.firstName=James').column('customer.lastName=James')
```

My use case is that after editing a record on a form view, the user gets sent back to a table view, on which I want to check the values have indeed updated.

Are there any useful recipes\approaches around that could help be here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an XPath to match the repeater and the text from the row with a single call:

```
element(by.xpath("//tr[@ng-repeat='customer in customers'][normalize-space(.)='Bob Smith']"))
```

Comment: Ok not quite what I had in mind, was hoping for something more readable using protractor locator style syntax! I'll give this a try out of curiosity anyhow. Thanks

Comment: An XPath is the way to go when you need to match some text. Sure, you could get all the rows with `element(by.repeater('customer in vm.customers')` and then filter them with `.filter(e => e.getText(v => v == 'Bob Smith'))`, but it would be much more expensive and harder to maintain.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at my protractor codelab. I have an exercise that does something very similar. Here is the code: https://github.com/andresdominguez/protractor-codelab/blob/ex3-solution/spec/list-helper.js#L13

And the test looks like:

```
it('should add user', function() {
  var name = 'test name ' + uniqueId;
  var email = 'foo' + uniqueId + '@gmail.com';
  var phone = '212-555-0000';

  userList.addUserButton.click();

  userProperties.name.sendKeys(name);
  userProperties.email.sendKeys(email);
  userProperties.phone.sendKeys(phone);
  userProperties.saveButton.click();

  expect(userList.list.getUsersByName(name)).toEqual([{
    name: name,
    email: email,
    phone: phone
  }]);
});
```

See the test: https://github.com/andresdominguez/protractor-codelab/blob/ex3-solution/spec/ex3-solution-spec.js#L13